# Android Firebase Auth: verify account and reset password within the App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, password-protection, password-recovery

I'm creating an App with the `Firebase` as a backend. Everything seems nice and smooth, but there are some questions concerning the Authentication.

1. `FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()` method sends an email which contains a link, that opens an INTERNET browser. It works fine, but is it possible to redirect and manage verification in the App ? Browser seems to be redundant in this work-flow.
2. Similarly, `FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail([email])` method uses a browser as the interface to change password. It'll be more convenient to change it within the App. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have both `sendEmailVerification` and `sendPasswordResetEmail` send Firebase Dynamic Links with action codes directly to the app by passing an ActionCodeSettings option with `canHandleCodeInApp` set to true. Learn more about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/passing-state-in-email-actions
In that case you would need to detect the incoming app link, use FDL to parse the deep link, get the action code and mode and build your own UI to verify the email or reset the password. You can port this guide to Android for more on this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: I'll check your approach later today, but it seems, you've saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer, but it's not quit clear of how to use a dynamic link with `sendPasswordResetEmail`? Should I alter the email template link in the Firebase Console? But how does it have to look like, and how will I pass the new password to the Service?

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation for full details. You don't alter the email template, you don't pass any new password. After you send the password reset email with the correct action code setting identifying your app, (make sure you configure FDL correctly), you then add logic to intercept the incoming link via an intent filter, parse the deep link with the FDL client library, you can then get the code, apply it and ask the user for the new password all in your app.